# Создание многомерного строкового массива

Tags: c++, массивы, char

```
const char DataBase[3][25] = { { "wo1fram", "Сава Знатнов", "qwerty" }, { "cyka", "сука", "cyka" } };
```

выдает ошибку **error C2078: слишком много инициализаторов**
прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: А куда вы хотите воткнуть шесть строк? Вот как вы планируете обратиться к суке, например? :)

Comment: я хотел сделать проверку если введенный пользователем логин и пароль совпадает с wo1fram (логин) и qwerty (пароль) то его пускает в главное меню, а если нет то вон отсюда!
3 суки я ввел как пример, там может быть например { "Julia", "Юлия Чацкая", "12345678" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли *звёздочку* (`*`) для *указателей* на `char` - вместо

```
const char DataBase[3][25] = { { "wo1fram", "Сава Знатнов", "qwerty" }, { "cyka", "сука", "cyka" } };
```

напишите

```
const char * DataBase[3][25] = { { "wo1fram", "Сава Знатнов", "qwerty" }, { "cyka", "сука", "cyka" } };
```

иначе ожидается массив *символов*, а уже у `"wo1fram"` их более чем 3.

Comment: благодарю вас! а почему именно так надо было сделать, получается это массив указателей?

Comment: Указатель на `char` - это практически *массив символов*, т. е. *строка*. А вы хотите массив *строк*.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, судя по вашим примерам у вас `[3]` и `[25]` перепутаны местами. Должно быть `[25][3]`, а не `[3][25]`. Эту ошибку вы еще просто не обнаружили.

Во-вторых, что касается вашей исходной ошибки: либо

```
const char *DataBase[25][3] = 
{ 
  { "wo1fram", "Сава Знатнов", "qwerty" }, 
  { "cyka", "сука", "cyka" } 
};
```

либо

```
const char DataBase[25][3][N] = 
{ 
  { "wo1fram", "Сава Знатнов", "qwerty" }, 
  { "cyka", "сука", "cyka" } 
};
```

(где `N` - некая максимальная длина строки).

А уж как правильно и нужен ли вам `const char *` или `const char [N]`  - нам отсюда не видно.